# Help drawing circle in iPhone

Tags: iphone, core-graphics

The following is a snippet of code where I am trying to draw a circle but my x value prints as a constant value. It's most likely something very very simple. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
int sides = 100;
int radius = 200;
int centerX = 100;
int centerY = 100;
CGFloat red[4] = {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
CGContextSetStrokeColor(context, red);
CGContextBeginPath(context);


CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, 0);
int i = 0;
for(i = 0; i <= sides; i++)
{

    CGFloat pointRatio = i/sides;
    CGFloat xSteps = cos( pointRatio * 2 * M_PI);
    CGFloat ySteps = sin( pointRatio * 2 * M_PI );
    CGFloat pointX = centerX + xSteps * radius;
    CGFloat pointY = centerY + ySteps * radius;
    NSLog(@"%i", pointX);

    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, pointX, pointY);
}
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
CGFloat pointRatio = i/sides;
```

When you divide 2 integers the result will be also integer - 0 in your case. You must ensure that floating point division will be performed:

```
CGFloat pointRatio = 1.0f*i/sides;
// Or even better
CGFloat pointRatio = i/(CGFloat)sides;
```

By the way why don't you want to draw circle using built-in function:

```
CGPathAddEllipseInRect(path, NULL, 
           CGRectMake(centerX - radius, centerY - radius, 2*radius, 2*radius));
```

Comment: You could also just convert one side of the division or the other to a floating-point type; for example, `i/(CGFloat)sides`. But yeah, `CGPathAddEllipseInRect` is the proper way to do it; plotting a hecatogon yourself is the hard way.

Comment: @Peter, is there any difference between these two ways to divide? Or compiler finally makes them the same instructions?

Comment: Yours is a multiplication and a division; mine is a division alone. The compiler might very well optimize out the multiplication, but I would rather not write the code for it in the first place.

Comment: The reason not to draw the circle via a built in functions is that it will eventually be a distorted line and not a perfect circle. Thanks for the great answer.

Comment: Skawful: How will your circle become distorted? Are you repeatedly concatenating to the transformation matrix and accumulating some sort of error in it? How will plotting a hecatogon avoid this?

Answer (score 5):

You only need 2 lines of code to draw a real round circle. My sample code:

```
CGContextAddArc(contextRef,centerX,centerY,radius,0,2*3.1415926535898,1);
CGContextDrawPath(contextRef,kCGPathStroke);
```

Answer (score 0):

Previous answer is correct. Also, use cosf() and sinf(), not cos() and sin() - you're working with float precision.

Comment: “Previous answer” doesn't say much when they're all “answered Aug 05 '10”. You should refer to the answer by its author's name.

Comment: Matthew thanks, interestingly enough sin() and cos() give me enough resolution in the final drawing... would that meant that I should just use those? Or will i have problems later on doing that.